# Label the internal memory file At Run Time

Tags: java, android, io

I have an application that

1. takes data from the user and
2. creates a file in the internal memory based on the name entered by the user
3. and saves the user data.

But when the file is saved by that name, the `fileInputStream` does not respond to that name.
what should I do ?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_load_food);
    bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    Toolbar toolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.food_lood_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    file=bundle.getString("diname");

    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(file);
    String q=”123”;


    if (bundle.getString("activity").equals(q)) {


        String e1=editText1.getText().toString() +"/";


            fileOutputStream=openFileOutput(file,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            fileOutputStream.write(e1.getBytes());





    }
    String t="321";
    if (bundle.getString("activity").equals(t)){
            try {
                fileInputStream= openFileInput(file);
                int x;
                StringBuffer y = new StringBuffer();
                while((x=fileInputStream.read())!=-1){
                y.append((char)x);
                }
                String c=y.toString();
                txt=c.split("/");

            editText1.setText(txt[0]);



        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"file not found",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"io",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
                try {
                    fileInputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

}

Comment: Why don't you use SharedPreferences? It also stores data in files.

Comment: Iwant Save Big Data

Comment: You can store String of any length in shared preferences. And regarding your question, what error did you get?

Comment: My problem is in the name FileoutputStream and FileInputStream when I name them

Depending on what the user enters